# How to correctly use lmer for mixed-effects model?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have data of an experiment where subjects (`ID`) have to perform 10 `trials` of a go/no-go task. I want to study the influence of the `decision` (go/no-go) on some physiological measure (e.g. `pupil.diameter`) during trial. I want to study that alongside other variables, some dependant on the subject (e.g. `age`), and other dependant on the trial (e.g. `difficulty`).

My data looks like this:

```
    ID  trial   decision   pupil.diameter   age      difficulty
0   1   1       go         3.2              47       easy
1   1   2       go         2.4              47       hard
2   1   3       no-go      5.6              47       hard
3   1   4       go         5.1              47       hard
.   .   .       .          .                .        .
9   1   10      go         3.4              47       easy
10  2   1       no-go      3.6              29       easy
11  2   2       go         4.2              29       hard
.   .   .       .          .                .        .
```

I would originally perform (under `R`) linear model/anova analyses like this:
`pupil.diameter ~  age + difficulty + decision`
with possibly interaction effects.

The problem is that some of my variables are dependant either on the `ID` or the `trial` (and thus their values repeated across multiple lines).

My search led me to consider a mixed-effects model and to use `lmer`, but I am still confused on how to do it correctly.

---

Is a mixed-effects model suitable here?

How to specify the random effects correctly?

Should I declare my model like this?

`pupil.diameter ~  age + difficulty + decision + (1|ID)`

Or like this???

`pupil.diameter ~  age + difficulty + decision + (1|trial)`

`pupil.diameter ~  age + difficulty + decision + (1|ID) + (1|trial)`

`pupil.diameter ~  age + difficulty + decision + (age|ID) + (difficulty|trial)`

---

NB: To generalise the example:

- subject-dependant variables could also be categorical (e.g. `gender`);
- trial-dependant variables could also be continuous (e.g. `difficulty` on a scale of 1 to 10);
- variable to explain could also be categorical (e.g. `blinked.during.trial?`) and the model would be adapted to a logistic regression;
- etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, this is definitely a good situation for a mixed model. The random intercepts/slopes you use depends on a few factors, such as the desired interpretation and power. I would start at the simplest (random intercept) model, and add your random effects in terms of importance; because without a huge sample you can run into issues with convergence. So starting off with

```
pupil.diameter ~ (1|ID) + age + difficulty + decision
```

which gives each subject their own intercept, then adding single random effects from there. I think [this](https://rpsychologist.com/r-guide-longitudinal-lme-lmer) could be what you are looking for when it comes to fitting an lme4 mixed model in R. This also shows how to use the nlme package, in-case that makes more sense naturally.